# SQL query for displaying clusters with their size

Tags: sql, count, aggregate-functions

I have a Table with different Cluster ID's

```
ID  
1  
1  
2  
2      
2    
3  
3  
3  
3  
4  
4
```

I want to display the size of the Cluster with No of Clusters in that Cluster.

For example for the above table Expected Output:

```
Cluster Size | No of Clusters (with that size)
2            | 2  
3            | 1  
4            | 1
```

I wrote a query which will give me the specified Cluster size.

```
Select COUNT(*) from  
(SELECT  ID, COUNT(ID) as cnt  
  FROM [Table] group by ID having COUNT(*) =3) as TC;
```

In the above example I will get "1" as my result for the above table.

However, I want a query which will give me all the Clusters and their respective size.

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to aggregate the aggregate. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select [Cluster Size], Count(*) as [No of Clusters]
from (
    select count(*) as [Cluster Size]
    from Table1
    group by ID
) a
group by [Cluster Size]
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56de3/9)

**Output:**

```
| CLUSTER SIZE | NO OF CLUSTERS |
---------------------------------
|            2 |              2 |
|            3 |              1 |
|            4 |              1 |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c AS ClusterSize, COUNT(*) AS NumOfClusters
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS c, ID
    FROM @table
    GROUP BY ID

)A
GROUP BY c
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements this query should do the job:

```
SELECT cl.size, COUNT(cl.size)
FROM
(SELECT id, COUNT(id) [Size] FROM Table1 GROUP BY id) cl
GROUP BY cl.size
```

Here is a link to SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56de3/7